Dyntopo not adding new geometry while using custom brushes from blenderkit
I tried using custom brushes, but the Dyntopo feature didn't work. I set it to constant detail at a value of 100, yet the brush behaved as if Dyntopo wasn't enabled. Does anyone have a solution?


Dynamic topology doesn't work with all brushes. Even the built-in brushes. Besides I wouldn't recommend it for anything really unless you've got a specific use case. If you just need more geo to sculpt on then just use the voxel remesh or multi-res modifier.

Thanks for clearing that up. I tried using the brush to add the dragon scales. I could just add more geometry to whole mesh but I try to avoid adding geometry that I won't be needing.

Yeah, it makes sense, but performance is much worse with Dyntopo. Any time you save by trying to pinch pennies on geo is probably going to be lost in the hindered performance.
